# Expand height in JtextArea dynamically

Tags: java, swing

how to change height of JTeaxtarea dynamically. i need to add scroll when it exceed the limit. please can anyone tell me how to this in java swing appilication.
thanx in advance

Comment: A `JScrollPane` using `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` would be a good start.  Check the [tutorial for scroll pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and get back to us with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code to add scroll bar to `JTextArea`.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20,10);
JScrollpane scrollPane = new JScrollpane(textArea);
```

This code will display horizantal and vertical scroll bars if you have more than 20 rows in your text area. You need to add `scrollPane` to `JPanel` or some pane as per your layout.